# MySQL remove duplicate issue

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

Here's the deal.

My database table has many columns. These 4 in particular is what I want to focus on:

```
BOL_NUMBER, CONTAINER_NUMBER, WORKFLOW, WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP
```

One BOL_NUMBER may have many CONTAINER_NUMBERs, with different WORKFLOWs (A CONTAINER_NUMBER can only have one BOL_NUMBER).  Every time a CONTAINER_NUMBER's WORKFLOW is updated, the WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP records the date and time it was updated, using the MySQL syntax NOW().

When the user does a search for a BOL_NUMBER (My test BOL_NUMBER is AAAA111111), the table returns 3 BOL_NUMBERs, all with 3 different CONTAINER_NUMBERs.

The current search returns this data:

```
 BOL_NUMBER     CONTAINER_NUMBER     WORKFLOW     WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP
 AAAA111111     TRLU1234567          UNASSIGNED   2014-01-21 12:00  
 AAAA111111     MAXU7894561          UNASSIGNED   2014-01-21 12:00
 AAAA111111     CMAU6543217          UNASSIGNED   2014-01-21 12:00
```

At this point, when the conditions for a CONTAINER_NUMBER are correct, the user can UPDATE the WORKFLOW to FULLY DISPATCHED.  For this case, I will use CONTAINER_NUMBER TRLU1234567.

When the CONTAINER_NUMBER has been updated, the user can perform another search just to verify if the WORKFLOW was indeed updated.

This is the search results after CONTAINER_NUMBER TRLU1234567 has been updated:

```
 BOL_NUMBER     CONTAINER_NUMBER     WORKFLOW          WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP
 AAAA111111     TRLU1234567          UNASSIGNED        2014-01-21 12:00 
 AAAA111111     TRLU1234567          FULLY DISPATCHED  2014-01-23 02:00 
 AAAA111111     MAXU7894561          UNASSIGNED        2014-01-21 12:00
 AAAA111111     CMAU6543217          UNASSIGNED        2014-01-21 12:00
```

As you see in the example above, there are now 2 instances of the CONTAINER_NUMBER TRLU1234567. ***Please note: the reason for this is keep track of when the WORKFLOW was updated***

With that said, I DO NOT want to return the duplicate CONTAINER_NUMBER. I only want to display the most recent WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP.

Basically, when the user does a search for BOL_NUMBER AAAA111111, it should only return the following:

```
 BOL_NUMBER     CONTAINER_NUMBER     WORKFLOW         WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP
 AAAA111111     TRLU1234567          FULLY DISPATCHED 2014-01-23 02:00  
 AAAA111111     MAXU7894561          UNASSIGNED       2014-01-21 12:00
 AAAA111111     CMAU6543217          UNASSIGNED       2014-01-21 12:00
```

The database table will have 4 instances of the BOL_NUMBER AAAA111111, but only display 3, like shown above, based on the WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP.

I hope I am being clear here.

Here is the code that I've been trying to use to make this work:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
    BOL_NUMBER,
    CONTAINER_NUMBER,
    WORKFLOW,
    MAX(WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP)
  FROM
    main_table
  WHERE
    BOL_NUMBER = 'AAAA111111'
  GROUP BY 
    BOL_NUMBER, CONTAINER_NUMBER;
```

But when I use the code above, I only return the original 3 CONTAINER_NUMBERs with the UNASSIGNED WORKFLOWs.  Even though the database table has 4 instances of the BOL_NUMBER.

I took DISTINCT out of the SELECT statement, but that gives me the same results.

When I remove the GROUP BY clause, it only returns 1 record with the most recent WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP, but displays UNASSIGNED in the WORKFLOW column.

I hope I am being clear here.  Basically, if the user does a search for a BOL_NUMBER, the code will check for the duplicate CONTAINER_NUMBER, check which one has the most recent WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP, and display THAT record, along with the rest of the records that are not duplicates.

I don't think I can be any clearer than that.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a unique key on this table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, I would use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` method to get the most recent workflow:

```
SELECT BOL_NUMBER, CONTAINER_NUMBER,
       substring_index(group_concat(WORKFLOW order by WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP desc), ',', 1) as WORKFLOW,
       MAX(WORKFLOW_DATESTAMP)
FROM main_table
WHERE BOL_NUMBER = 'AAAA111111'
GROUP BY BOL_NUMBER, CONTAINER_NUMBER;
```

Also, you normally shouldn't need `distinct` when you use `group by`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. However, another issue has arisen. But the code you provided works.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add a column to the db called "LAST_MODIFIED" and update that datetime with when the record was updated.  This will allow you to know when it was updated and will remove the need for separate entries.